# How do I download and install dhcpv6 on my server using Ubuntu?

Tags: dhcp, ipv6

I've downloaded dhcp3 on my server and I now need the server to assign ipv6 addresses. 
Also what is stateless autoconfiguration and how do I use it on my server?

Answer (score 1):

IPv6 address provisioning usually works like this:

- The router sends a Router Advertisement (RA).
  On Linux/Unix/etc this is done by RADVD

  - The RA indicates for how long the sending router can be used as default gateway
  - The RA contains flags that indicate the provisioning method used:

    - The (M)anaged flag indicates if there is a DHCP server for address assignment (stateful mode)
    - The (O)ther configuration flag indicates if there is a DHCP server for other configuration options (stateless DHCP: only provides options but does not do address management)
  - The RA contains the prefixes that are used on the LAN

    - Each prefix option indicates if that prefix can be used for (A)uto-configuration
  - RA's can also contain the addresses of DNS resolvers

StateLess Address Auto Configuration (SLAAC) is the name for when there are prefixes with the (A) option on in the RA. The systems then can configure their own IPv6 addresses based on those prefixes and use the router as default gateway. Optionally a stateless DHCP server can provide extra options (like domain name, DNS resolvers, time server, etc).

So if you want to configure your Linux box as a router you will need RADVD and optionally a DHCPv6 server in either stateful or stateless mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wide dhcpv6 server: `sudo apt-get install wide-dhcpv6-server`. More details would probably be available here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wide-dhcpv6/.

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, 10 year old answer, but you still might come across it.  Don't use the wide one.  Will it work? Yes, I got it to work quite well.  Will it tell you what it is doing (answering, or a leases files)? No..

The ISC one works well, just make sure it is looking at the right config file.

Comment: What you mean is not very clear. Are you suggesting that the OP should install `isc-dhcp-client` or something? Could you please [edit] your answer and clarify?